# Problema consumo WebService NFS-e

Tags: c#, web-service, erp

Estou tenho vários problemas no consumo do webservice de Joinville, SC.

Homologação: https://nfemwshomologacao.joinville.sc.gov.br/NotaFiscal/Servicos.asmx?wsdl
Produção: https://nfemws.joinville.sc.gov.br/NotaFiscal/Servicos.asmx?wsdl

Para consumir o WebService eu fiz dessa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E depois para consumir esse WebService, ficou mais ou menos assim:

```cs
private EnviarLoteRpsEnvio1 EmitirNFSe(X509Certificate2 certificado, EnviarLoteRpsEnvio envio)
{
#if DEBUG
   string enderecoBase = "https://nfemwshomologacao.joinville.sc.gov.br";
#else
   string enderecoBase = "https://nfemws.joinville.sc.gov.br";
#endif
   var client = new ServicosSoapClient(CriarBinding(), new EndpointAddress(enderecoBase + "/NotaFiscal/Servicos.asmx"));
   client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificado;
   return ((ServicosSoap)client).RecepcionarLoteRps(envio);
}
```

---

## Problema 1

Um dos problemas é que a classe `EnviarLoteRpsEnvio` esperada no método `cliente.RecepcionarLoteRps(envio)` tem 2 propriedades: `LoteRps` e `Signature`, ambos do tipo `XmlNode`:

```cs
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="EnviarLoteRpsEnvio", WrapperNamespace="https://nfemwshomologacao.joinville.sc.gov.br", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class EnviarLoteRpsEnvio {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="https://nfemwshomologacao.joinville.sc.gov.br", Order=0)]
    public System.Xml.XmlNode LoteRps;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="https://nfemwshomologacao.joinville.sc.gov.br", Order=1)]
    public System.Xml.XmlNode Signature;

    public EnviarLoteRpsEnvio() {
    }
}
```

Como faço para preencher esses campos? Eu criei uma classe `LoteRps` e preenchi com os dados pedidos pelo WebService, transformei em `XmlDocument` e coloquei nessa propriedade, mas o xml convertido (peguei pelo Fiddler) é gerado com a tag `LoteRps` duplicada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Problema 2

A consulta eu consegui fazer funcionar, porém eu tiver um erro em release:

```
Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: https://nfemwshomologacao.joinville.sc.gov.br/ConsultarNfseRpsEnvio.
```

Isso acontece pois o endereço de produção é outro. Veja como foi gerada a classe proxy:

```cs
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "https://nfemwshomologacao.joinville.sc.gov.br", ConfigurationName = "NFSe.Joinville.ServicosSoap")]
public interface ServicosSoap
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "https://nfemwshomologacao.joinville.sc.gov.br/EnviarLoteRpsEnvio", ReplyAction = "*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults = true)]
    Wiser.Servicos.NFSe.Joinville.EnviarLoteRpsEnvio1 RecepcionarLoteRps(Wiser.Servicos.NFSe.Joinville.EnviarLoteRpsEnvio request);

   /*Outros métodos*/
}
```

Está fixo o endereço de homologação

## Resumo

Na verdade eu tive vários problemas com esse WebService, então minha duvida é se estou consumindo da forma correta. Eu já consumi outros WebServices sem problema, esse foi o único que parece diferente.
Para a emissão da nota eu consegui fazer uma requisição http montando o request manualmente, sem usar as classes de proxy geradas para consumir o webservice. Mas isso deu muito trabalho. Alguma sugestão?